# Movie with an Alien race Which Absorbs Light as a Source of Nutrition

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv, energy

I watched this old cable TV movie when I was younger but I can't seem to find it anywhere in lists on the Internet.

I can't remember the year I've watched it but it was around the 2000s, so the movie is probably from the 90s or even the late 80s.

I remember that there was an alien female who was disguised as a human and for some reason she defected and was running with a human trying to prevent an invasion.

At some point she said that she has to feed/recharge and lowered her disguise - at which point she became pitch black, still with a humanoid body and laid down on the back seat of the car while the man was driving. She explained to him that their race is so much more advanced and doesn't need anything else for food but just sunlight.

**Edit:** The movie was American. The setting was in some big city, L.A., N.Y. or similar but I can't remember which one exactly. They entered in a small spaceship at some point and were flying through the city skyscrapers. At the happy ending a huge alien mothership appears.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. Is there any more details you can give us about the film, what language it was in, or any names of characters? If you remember anything else either comment or [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/149830/edit) your post to add in the details. Also, feel free to take the [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Damn, I think I've seen this film as well but can't add any more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be [The Sender (1998)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0138089/reference).

> I remember that there was an alien female who was disguised as a human and for some reason she defected and was running with a human trying to prevent an invasion.

Alien disguised as human female, yes. No defection; she (Angel) is assigned to watch/guard a (human) widower, Dallas Grayson, and his young daughter Lisa, who respectively carry and manifest a special gene for a form of psychokinesis called sending. Lisa is kidnapped by a secret government/military project who want to exploit this power, and Angel helps Dallas try to rescue Lisa from that misuse through a long series of chases and fights.

> At some point she said that she has to feed/recharge and lowered her disguise - at which point she became pitch black, still with a humanoid body and laid down on the back seat of the car while the man was driving. She explained to him that their race is so much more advanced and doesn't need anything else for food but just sunlight.

Yes, she 'feeds' off sunlight in the back seat of Dallas' convertible. This is established in dialogue, but in the DVD version I have we don't actually see her lying down and nudity is only implied; assuming you mean premium cable maybe that showed more. In the last scene we do see several others of her 'kind' as all-black and kind of Gumby-shaped (and apparently unclothed).

> The movie was American. The setting was in some big city, L.A., N.Y. or similar but I can't remember which one exactly. They entered in a small spaceship at some point and were flying through the city skyscrapers. At the happy ending a huge alien mothership appears

All close. The setting is LA plus nearby roads and desert. She has a small flying 'ship' which is used only at low altitude and AFAICT not described as space-capable; they fly it back to central LA where they are chased around the skyscrapers by several villain helicopters, eventually shooting her ship down (into one of the flood-control channels that feature in seemingly all movies and TV shows set in LA). The alien mothership appears in the opening/prologue *and* the ending.

If so, this is the same movie as [this other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112791/help-with-identification-of-old-movie-about-aliens)

Comment: Yes, that's the same movie! Thank you very much for identifying it! Maybe I've got the part with her on the back seat imagined, I don't know. Or there is some other uncut version which would be weird that isn't on the DVD. The cable wasn't a premium, in my country then it was only one operator for the whole city with 1 or 2 plans at most.

Answer (score 0):

The film could be "Lifeforce" from 1985 starring Peter Firth and Mathilda May.

Comment: Lifeforce is about space vampires.  Vampires are not usually even able to survive sunlight, much less absorb energy from it (although I admit I remember very little about the movie).  Could you elaborate on why you think this is the answer?

Comment: Sadly that's not the movie. Lifeforce is made in the UK. The one I'm talking about is made in the USA and happens in there, as I've explained.